# Large-scale box-constrained linear least-squares

Tags: least-squares, constrained-optimization

I need to solve

$$\mbox{min}||Ax - b||_2^2 \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad l \leq x \leq u,$$

where $A \in R^{m \times n}$, $m \ll n$, $n \approx 10^4-10^5$.

BVLS [1] based on active-set method works fine for small problems, but it is too slow for large-scale problems I have.

Are there any other (maybe approximate) methods to deal with such problems?

[1] http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/Preprints/bvls.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bound-constrained case, MATLAB defaults to using a trust-region reflective method found in Coleman, T.F. and Y. Li, "A Reflective Newton Method for Minimizing a Quadratic Function Subject to Bounds on Some of the Variables," SIAM Journal on Optimization, Vol. 6, Number 4, pp. 1040-1058, 1996. You might try that method, and see how it works out.

For very large scale problems, I'd probably use algorithms in [TAO](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/tao/) tailored to quadratic problems, such as GPCG or BQPIP.

Comment: Geoff, thanks. I have tried MATLAB's routines an they all fail for my problems. Maybe be I just have to tweak parameters better.